# Hide div on outside click using knockout?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

How to hide a div on outside click using knockout.js... I have tried this but did not succeeded..

html:

```
<body>
<div data-bind="visible: show">
    <h3>hello world</h1>
</div>

<input type='button' data-bind="click: showBox" value="show"/>

    <body>
```

script:

```
var viewModel = function()
{
    self = this;
    self.show =  ko.observable(false);
    self.showBox = function(){
            self.show(true);
        $("body").one("click", function(){

                self.show(false);
        });
     };
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

> [Here is fiddler example:](http://jsfiddle.net/imranpk/cFvKw/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you want to hide the div only if the user clicks anywhere but on the div, you'll have to add `stopPropagation()` to the div's click event, and also the button's click event because otherwise the body's click event will fire immediately, hiding the div every time you try to click the button. Note that this will make it so clicking the button once the div is shown won't make the div be hidden... You'll also need to move `$("body").on("click"...` to outside of showBox.

The model:

```
var viewModel = function()
{
    self = this;
    self.show =  ko.observable(false);
    self.showBox = function(){
            self.show(true);
     };
     $("body").on("click", function(){
         self.show(false);
     });
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

The HTML:

```
<div data-bind="visible: show, click: function(data, event) { event.stopPropagation(); }">
    <h3>hello world</h1>
</div>

<input type='button' data-bind="click: function(data, event) { showBox(data); event.stopPropagation(); }" value="show"/>
```

And a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonhopkins/wvHaZ/1/)

Comment: no i want to hide if user click anywhere on document except that specific div

Comment: Changed the answer to do what you want.